# How to use z-index or any other method to position an element in bootstrap carousel?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, position

The output I am trying to achieve is this,
[Sample image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCSfi.png)

I tried using z-index and positioning but, I couldn't achieve the output. [My work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDXaW.png)

I am stuck with the following and could not move the testimonial person image half inside and half outside the background.

Here is my HTML code,

```
<section id="testimonials">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h2 class="medium-title">What they’ve said</h1>
  <div id="testimonial-slider" class="carousel slide" data-ride="true">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="https://ibb.co/Y38pJpk" alt="Anisha Li">
        <h6>Anisha Li</h6>
        <p class="testimonial-text">“Manage has supercharged our team’s workflow. The ability to maintain
          visibility on larger milestones at all times keeps everyone motivated.”</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/avatar-ali.png" alt="Ali Bravo">
        <h6>Ali Bravo</h6>
        <p>“We have been able to cancel so many other subscriptions since using
          Manage. There is no more cross-channel confusion and everyone is much
          more focused.”</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/avatar-richard.png" alt="Richard Watts">
        <h6>Richard Watts</h6>
        <p>“Manage allows us to provide structure and process. It keeps us organized
          and focused. I can’t stop recommending them to everyone I talk to!”</p>
      </div>
      <div class="carousel-item">
        <img class="testimonial-image" src="images/avatar-shanai.png" alt="Shanai Gough">
        <h6>Shanai Gough</h6>
        <p>“Their software allows us to track, manage and collaborate on our projects
          from anywhere. It keeps the whole team in-sync without being intrusive.”</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#testimonial-slider" role="button" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#testimonial-slider" role="button" data-slide="next">
      <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
  <button class="btn button-red" type="button" name="button">Get Started</button>
</div>
```

How to change the position of the image?

Codeply link: https://www.codeply.com/p/PbBtENblHD

Just so that it would be easy to have a look around.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution. The 'carousel-inner' class had overflow: hidden; property, so the image was getting hidden. For all those of you new to bootstrap, if you face a similar problem make sure to check the overflow property of the default bootstrap classes.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe try some [relative positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)

Comment: When I use relative positioning, it goes under and not on top of the background.

Comment: Is there any other way @Mateusz Kowalewski